# URL redirecting to wrong place when urls are similar

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here is part of my **.htaccess** file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule tilaukset home.php?page=orders
RewriteRule tilaustenhallinta home.php?page=ordersManage
RewriteRule jarjestelmaraportit home.php?page=ordersReports
RewriteRule kaikki-tilaukset home.php?page=allOrders
RewriteRule keskeneraiset-tilaukset home.php?page=inProgressorders
RewriteRule valmiit-tilaukset home.php?page=completedOrders
RewriteRule tuotannossa-tilaukset home.php?page=inProductionorders
RewriteRule lahetetyt-tilaukset home.php?page=shippedOrders
```

By clicking this element `<a href="tilaukset">Tilaukset</a>` it redirects to correct place (*which is orders.php*), but when I click another link with different properties `<a href="kaikki-tilaukset">Kaikki tilaukset</a>` it still opens the same file. When I remove "*tilaukset*" from "*Kaikki tilaukset*" and just leave it as "*Kaikki*". Like so:

```
RewriteRule kaikki home.php?page=allOrders
```

It works correctly and nothing bad happens. For some reason it doenst check the whole argument. It finds same word and then uses that. How to fix this?

Comment: RewriteRule tilaukset home.php?page=orders means any uri contains  tilaukset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line :

```
RewriteRule tilaukset home.php?page=orders
```

means any URI contains `tilaukset` it will capture a `kaikki-tilaukset` as well

change it to :

```
RewriteRule ^tilaukset home.php?page=orders
```

This `^` means start with tilaukset .

The other Rule:

```
RewriteRule kaikki-tilaukset home.php?page=allOrders
```

Should work fine right now.

Comment: @JaakkoUusitalo glad to help , Thanks